# How to deploy corda project to the server

Tags: corda

I have made a simple project in Corda. My project has 4 nodes including notary and also SpringBoot APIs in the clients folders. I don't know how to deploy my project to the server. I saw the Corda docs but that tutorial was for a single node. So, my question is how to deploy the Corda project with Multiple nodes on the Server and also the SpringBoot APIs. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually some good youtube videos on this (from me!).

You can find that here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NtVbkUCSt7s

There's other videos there for GCP and Azure as well.

Essentially you need to make sure that your corda node config's p2pAddress specifies the IP address of the machine in your cloud provider of choice.

Comment: Thabks Davidawas, But I want to deploy my project on server of my company. Do I still need to use AWS or Azure. Would these videos be still helpful?

Comment: the videos will still be helpful, just make sure the machines you use for corda instances are able to talk to each other (meaning IP addrs are reachable).